# Syntax Errors in QuizGame and Tips

Tags: java

I am learning programming and I was wondering why I am getting errors, I don't know where to begin. Please ignore static void Question_Four to Ten and the comments. I also need tips on how to improve my code. Thanks for the help,
ThawingOrb.

```
/**
 * @(#)QuizGameFinal2.java
 *
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2013/4/30
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.String;
public class QuizGameFinal2
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

    int option_Selected;
    int option_Single_Player = 1;
    int option_Multiplayer = 2;
    int answer;
    int player_One_Answer;
    int player_Two_Answer;
    String response;
    int player_One_Winnings;
    int player_Two_Winnings;
    int winnings;
    int computer_Winnings;
    double computer_Answer;

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);


    say_Intro();
    say_Before_First_Question();
    question_One();
    human_Answer();
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
    } while (answer < 1 && answer => 4);

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct Next Question");
        question_Two();
        human_Answer();
        do
        {
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 4");
        } while (answer < 1 && answer >= 5);

        if (answer == 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("Correct Next Question");
            question_Three();
            human_Answer();
        do
        {
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 4");
        } while (answer < 1 && answer >= 5);


            if (answer == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Correct Next Question");

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect you win 1000 dollers");
                winnings = 1000;
            }

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect you win 500 dollers");
            winnings = 500;
        }


    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect you win 0 dollers");
        winnings = 0;
    }





    } // End of main method




    static void say_Intro()     // Intro Method
    {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the QuizGame");          // Player selects which mode
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Single Player");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for Multiplayer");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                                 // Scanner for the entire game
    int option_Selected = input.nextInt();

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2");
       } while (option_Selected != 1 || option_Selected != 2);

    }


    public void say_Before_First_Question()     // Before game method
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the quiz game.");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
            System.out.print("Your response");
            response = input.next();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(" If you get a question wrong your out ok?");
            System.out.print("Your Response:");
            response = input.next();
            System.out.println("Also you will be competing against a super computer, after you play then he will generate answers, if you have the most then you win");
            System.out.println("Ok first question");
        }

    static void human_Answer ()         // Human Answer Single Player Method
    {

        int answer=input2.nextInt();
    }

    static void player_One_Answer()     // Player One Multiplayer Method
    {
        int player_One_Answer = input2.nextInt();
    }

    static void player_Two_Answer()     // Player two multiplayer Method
    {
        int player_Two_Answer = input2.nextInt();
    }

    static void computer_Answer ()      // Computer answer
    {
        double computer_Answer = (1-1 + 1) * Math.random + 1;
               computer_Answer = (int)computer_Answer;
    }

    static void question_One()          // Question 1 method
    {
        System.out.println("What is an application");
        System.out.println("1: A program that performs a task   2:A mouse   3: java.util.Scanner");


    }

    static void question_Two()      // Question 2 to 10 methods below
    {

        System.out.println("What is the data type that hold the value 1");
        System.out.println("1: int  2:float 3: short 4: long ");

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 4");
        } while (answer < 1 && answer > 5);

    }

    static void question_Three()
    {
        System.out.println("What is a not a high level language");
        System.out.println("1: Java     2:C++   3: Colbolt      4: Machine Language ");

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3");       // Do this if the person enters a number less than one and greater than 3
        } while (answer < 1 && answer > 4);

    }

/*  static void question_Five()
    {

    }

    static void question_Six()
    {

    }

    static void question_Seven()
    {

    }

    static void question_Eight()
    {

    }

    static void question_Nine()
    {

    }

    static void question_Ten()
    {

    }

    static void total_Winnings_Single_Player ()     // Calculating who wins method single player
    {
        if (computer_Winnings > winnings)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer Wins");
        }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("You win");
            }
            */
    }




  // End of program
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Learn to debug your code. And if you are using good IDE (i.e., Eclipse), it should detect places with errors very well. There are at least two obvious errors I see, which could've been fixed in 5 seconds if you have a proper IDE.

Comment: I can't use Debugger if there is a syntax error (Don't know if that is java wide or just my IDE) (I use J-Creator) and it does not have the obvious errors fix up because I do not have Eclipse. (J creator)

Comment: Download Eclipse. It is free and awesome - you'll thank yourself for it...

Answer (score 1):

Your program is a nearly-indecipherable tangle of code. Let's improve the structure of your program. First, note that the logic for processing the questions is the same for all questions. It would be useful to define a `Question` class that encapsulates the question-specific data. You can then write the logic once. The `Question` class might look like this (including a constructor to initialize the `Question` object):

```
class Question {
    /** The text of the question itself */
    public String question;

    /** The array of possible answers */
    public String[] answers;

    /** The index (zero-based) of the correct answer */
    public int correctAnswer;

    /** Construct a Question with the given values */
    public Question(String question, String[] answers, int correct) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correct = correct;
    }
}
```

It also makes sense to let the question print itself. So let's add a `printQuestion` method to the `Question` class:

```
class Question {
    . . . // as above

    public void printQuestion() {
        System.out.println(question);
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + ": " + answers[i] + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now let's turn to the main program. You are creating a new `Scanner` object every time you need input from the user. You only need one `Scanner`, but it needs to be accessible to all code that will need it. There are two options: either add a `Scanner` parameter to each method that needs input or make the `Scanner` an instance variable of the `QuizGameFinal2` class. The latter makes the most sense:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuizGameFinal2 {
    Scanner input2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        . . .
    }
}
```

Note that you never need to import classes (like `Math` and `String`) from the `java.lang` package; they are automatically imported. Now you can start writing logic for processing the questions. First, write a general method for printing a question and obtaining the user's answer (this will be a member of `QuizGameFinal2`):

```
public static int questionAndAnswer(Question question) {
    question.printQuestion();
    int n = question.answers.length;
    int answer = input2.nextInt();
    while (answer < 1 || answer > n) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and " + n);
        answer = input2.nextInt();
    }
    return answer - 1; // subtract 1 so it is a zero-based index
}
```

Now we can continue developing the `main()` method. Here's an outline of how it might go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Question[] questions = {
        new Question("What is an application?",
            new String[] {"A program that performs a task",
                          "A mouse",
                          "java.util.Scanner"},
            0
        ),
        new Question("What is the data type that hold the value 1?",
            new String[] {"int", "float", "short", "long"},
            0
        ),
        . . . // etc.
    }
    say_Intro();
    say_Before_First_Question();
    for (Question q : questions) { // iterates through the questions in order
        int answer = questionAndAnswer(q);
        if (answer == q.answer) {
            System.out.println("Correct! Next Question");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. You're out!");
            return;
        }
        // TODO: get computer answer; calculate winnings
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

There's obviously a lot more that you want in your program, but perhaps this will get you onto a more productive path.

Answer (score 0):

Greater or equal should be `>=` not `=>`.

---

The method `say_Before_First_Question` needs to be static to be called from another static method (main).

Change the method definition to:

`public static void say_Before_First_Question()`

---

`Math.random` is a method so you need the `()`. It should be `Math.random()`

Comment: Now when making a method is it public static void or static void?

Comment: You can use either, `public` says that you can call the method from another class. You could also use `private` instead of `public` if you will only call the methods in this class.

Comment: Also I have 12 errors "Cannot find symbol" for all my variables in the methods, do I have to put the data type in front of them either though I declared them in the main method.

Comment: If you declare variables in the main method they are only available in the main method. You will need to pass them to the other methods or declare them in the class.